# Recursion in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, mergesort

I was trying to do merge sort in a different way (instead of those available in texts or so..), now I have a successful merge algorithm, but the thing is that when I recursively call on half lists, the merged thing doesn't get updated. Help me with variable life in the recursion.

The output of the below-given code is: -

```
[9, 5]
After merging [5, 9]
[12, 4]
After merging [4, 12]
[9, 5, 12, 4] #it should be (the updated one i.e  [5, 9, 4, 12])
After merging [5, 9, 12, 4]
[6, 8]
After merging [6, 8]
[45, 2]
After merging [2, 45]
[6, 8, 45, 2]
After merging [6, 8, 45, 2]
[9, 5, 12, 4, 6, 8, 45, 2]
After merging [4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 45, 2]
[9, 5, 12, 4, 6, 8, 45, 2]
```

---

```
def merge(arr1, arr2):
"""
Input is two sorted lists
Output is a single merged list
"""
        for i in arr1:
            for j in list(range(len(arr2))):
                if i<arr2[j]:
                    arr2.append(arr2[-1])
                    for count in list(range(len(arr2)-1, j, -1)):
                        arr2[count] = arr2[count-1]
                    arr2[j] = i
                    break
                if j == len(arr2)-1:
                    arr2.append(i)
        return arr2
    def mergeSort(arr):
        if len(arr) !=1:
            mergeSort(arr[:len(arr)//2])
            mergeSort(arr[len(arr)//2:])
            print(arr)
            arr = merge(arr[:len(arr)//2],arr[len(arr)//2:])
            print("After merging", arr)

        else:
            return arr
    a = [9,5,12, 4, 6, 8,45, 2]
    mergeSort(a)
    print(a)
```

Comment: Hint: Is the caller's version of `arr` ever being modified in `mergeSort`? Further hint: Slicing a `list` makes a shallow copy of it, so modifications to a slice of a `list` don't change the original `list` at all. Lastly: `x = ANYTHING` *rebinds* `x`, it doesn't modify any other references to whatever `x` used to refer to.

Comment: OKAY...arr is never getting modified... I got this.. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only make sooo little changes so the code remain yours with your effort, you were so close, look:

The thing is, after reviewing your code, you have to pass the two halves to the merge method, and also check if it is empty. Besides, is considerably better to return the results and not make changes in place-

```
def merge(arr1, arr2):
        for i in arr1:
            for j in list(range(len(arr2))):
                if i<arr2[j]:
                    arr2.append(arr2[-1])
                    for count in list(range(len(arr2)-1, j, -1)):
                        arr2[count] = arr2[count-1]
                    arr2[j] = i
                    break
                if j == len(arr2)-1:
                    arr2.append(i)
        return arr2
def mergeSort(arr):
    if len(arr) !=1 and len(arr):
        ary1 = mergeSort(arr[:len(arr)//2])
        ary2 = mergeSort(arr[len(arr)//2:])
        print(arr)
        ary3 = merge(ary1,ary2)
        print("After merging", ary3)
        return ary3
    else:
        return arr
a = [9,5,12, 4, 6, 8,45, 2]

print(mergeSort(a))
```

the output

```
[9, 5]
After merging [5, 9]
[12, 4]
After merging [4, 12]
[9, 5, 12, 4]
After merging [4, 5, 9, 12]
[6, 8]
After merging [6, 8]
[45, 2]
After merging [2, 45]
[6, 8, 45, 2]
After merging [2, 6, 8, 45]
[9, 5, 12, 4, 6, 8, 45, 2]
After merging [2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 45]
[2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 45]
```

Answer (score 3):

You should make `mergeSort` return the merged list, and the caller should output the returning value of `mergeSort` instead:

```
def merge(arr1, arr2):
    merged = []
    while arr1 and arr2:
        if arr1[0] > arr2[0]:
            arr1, arr2 = arr2, arr1
        merged.append(arr1.pop(0))
    merged.extend(arr1 or arr2)
    return merged
def mergeSort(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr
    return merge(mergeSort(arr[:len(arr)//2]), mergeSort(arr[len(arr)//2:]))
a = [9, 5, 12, 4, 6, 8, 45, 2]
print(mergeSort(a))
```

Comment: I really like your answer and your explanation, and it is so clean... it's a plus one well deserved

Comment: Note that the implementation here is wrong although the answer demonstrates what the question wanted. Try `a= [1, 2, 3, 4]`. The way to fix it and the explanation for how it is wrong is left as an exercise for the reader. ;)

Comment: @ShioT Ah indeed I wasn't thinking with a clear head. Fixed now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @blhsing You might as well leave it there haha

Comment: It was nice, coz I got my answer, but the constraint which I had got from my professor was not to use any extra space for merging the lists, that's why I didn't go for comparing the top of the lists and putting the large one in a separate list.